# Index out of range when attempting to seed database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

**What is happening:**

I'm trying to seed my database with company details when I run `Update-Database`. However, for some reason that I can't understand it would seem as if the code in my `Seed` helper-method ignores when one of its helpers returns `null`.

---

**What I'm doing:**

The idea is rather simple:

Iterate over a file with a bunch of identifiers and send a `HttpWebRequest` to an API to get the details using the identier. Then parse the response to a `Company` object.

However if it turns out that one of the identifiers don't exist in the API (if the `Request.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Ok`) I return `null`. Or if the surrounding `try-catch` fails, I return `null`.

**IT SHOULD BE NOTED THAT I KNOW THAT THE FIRST IDENTIFIER IN MY LIST RETURNS A NON-OK STATUSCODE!**

---

**The Problem:**

The `null` is never caught in my calling code (the first snippet bellow), so it would seem as if it is attempting to parse the empty `JObject`, which gives me this error message:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

**Calling Code:**

```
string[] symbols = Resources.Fixed_lines.Split(' ');

int stockId = 1;

foreach(var symbol in symbols)
{
    var stockData = GetStockDataFromSymbol(symbol);

    if (stockData != null)
    {
        var json = JObject.Parse(stockData);

        var stock = new Company()
        {
            StockId = stockId,
            Name = json["datatable"]["data"][0][1].ToString(),
            Description = json["datatable"]["data"][0][0].ToString(),
            Symbol = symbol
        };

        _context.Stocks.Add(stock);
        stockId++;
    } else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The `HttpWebRequest` helper:

```
private string GetStockDataFromSymbol(string symbol)
{
    try
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/ZACKS/CP.json?" +
                "qopts.columns[]=comp_desc&qopts.columns[]=comp_name&ticker={0}" +
                "&api_key=myApiKey", symbol);
        Debug.WriteLine(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.
            Create(url);
        request.Method = "Get";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string responseBody = string.Empty;
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return responseBody;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20940979/447156 ?

Comment: Not sure if that really helps me. The problem I seem to face is more regarding the fact that the null doesn't seem to be found in the calling code, even though it should be returned by the called code.

Comment: You have some hard coded indexes, like `json["datatable"]["data"][0][1]`. The error is saying that even though neither `stockData` nor `json` are null, one of the indexes you're referencing doesn't exist. Set a breakpoint on `var stock = new Company()` and check the value of `json`.